# Breaking out from nested for loops

Tags: javascript, html

I have two for loops want exit from two loops my control is at  inner loop  see the below code

```
for(condition)
{
    for (condition)
    {
         if(condition)
                  from here i want to exit from these loops 
     }
}
```

Comment: Most of the answers below are reasonable.  But I would also suggest that if you start building deeply nested control structures, you might want to rethink your design.  This might be ok, but any deeper is treading on uncomfortable ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a flag and if the flag falls break out of both of them.

```
var flag = true;

for(condition && flag)
{
    for (condition && flag)
    {
         if(condition) {
             flag = false;
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DasariVinodh You are welcome :) Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20725904/1903116), thats supposed to be the way to go.

Comment: @DasariVinodh: This will fail to do what you want in some cases. If there's any code inside the first loop, and after the nested loop, it'll still run one last time after setting the flag. Use a `break` statement instead.

Answer (score 10):

JS uses statement labels to give statements identifiers. This is great for use on nested loops, because it can give your inner statement control of what's happening beyond its 'tier' of loop. Statement labels can be used with either the continue or break statements.

So your code can be:

```
someName: 
for(condition)
{
    for (condition)
    {
         if(condition)
                  if (condition) {
                      break someName; // exit outer loop
                  }
     }
}
```

For more info, see [MDN "label"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: weird. I didn't realize this was a thing.

Answer (score 2):

While jpau's recipe is fine and reminiscent of C/C++, I will prefer a recipe with [curry's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry) flavor.

Just wrap your loop in an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
(function(){
  for(condition) {
    for (condition) {
      if(condition) {
         // do whatever here
         return;
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

Because [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is first-class object in JavaScript, you can leverage of IIFE without resorting to lalels.

Comment: What is meant by "resorting to labels"? IMO, it's a much cleaner and more readable syntax than using an IIFE like this.

Comment: labels, while legal, is not a good option in javascript. Javascript supports code block `{foo: bar()}` and plain object like `{foo: bar()}`. There are rules to distinguish them but does it really bother to force users to remember the bad part of javascript?

Comment: That syntax problem exists either way. It doesn't make labels a bad option. Not using labels where appropriate doesn't fix anything.

Comment: That's purely of personal preference, though.

Answer (score 1):

Write your nested loops into a **seperate function** and then use `return` to get out of the loop from anywhere, rather than `break`.

```
function myFunction()
{
    for(condition)
    {
        for (condition)
        {
             if(condition)

                      if (condition) 
                      {
                         return;
                      }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Herrington Darkholme's answer is better, please check that too :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: Ramshad's answer is arguably better than Herrington's (given that a function is going to be used) because it at least breaks the code up into smaller parts and substitutes a descriptive name. Something that one may want anyway.